# How do I plot a custom function with logarithmic scaling of x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm relatively new to Matlab. All I want to do is plot the sequence `x = @(n) 1/n^n` from `0` to `10`. With natural scaling first and then wit logarithmic scaling of x-axis.

I've tried to use `semilogx` for the second plot. However, I've alway get an error message:

> Undefined function 'semilog' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

If I try to define `x` in the following way: `n = 0:.01:10; x = 1/n.^n;`I get the error message:

> Matrix dimensions must agree

How I need to define `x` and plot both graphs?

Comment: Note that the use of an anonymous function is not required, as @Luis mentioned the main problem is that you didn't use `./` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case n is a vector so you must first define your anonymous function using Matlab array operators for division and exponentiation like this:

```
x = @(n) 1./n.^n
```

Then take for example:

```
n = [0:.01:10];
```

And now make your plot:

```
figure; semilogx(n,x(n)); grid on;
```

Which gives a plot like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
x = @(n) 1./n.^n
n = 0:.01:10;
semilogx(x(n))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `.` before the `/`:

```
n = 0:.01:10; x = 1./n.^n;
plot(n,x)
figure
semilogx(n,x)
```

In your code as it stands, `1/n.^n` is interpreted as "the inverse of `n.^n`", where `n.^n` is a vector; and the inverse of a vector is undefined. What you want is the *element-wise* inverse of that vector, and for that you need the extra `.` before the `/`.